# net send problem

Tags: command-line

Can anyone help me figure out why I can't use net send in cmd prompt to send message to other computers? I did test by using the following commands :

```
net send * test
```

code above is working. I success receive the message on my own computer, but fail to receive the message on all other computers in the network.

```
net send 192.168.1.6 test
```

code above is not working. It gives error "The message alias could not be found on the network. (192.168.1.6) is my own computer.

```
net view
```

code above success shows all the computer name on the network.

```
net name
```

code above is fail, give errors : `There are no entries in the list`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the messenger service on the remote computers? It is required for receiving messages from `net send` but is disabled by default on Windows XP SP2 and later because schoolchildren kept doing things like `net send * test`.

> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839018

Comment: It's more because of "Your computer is infected" popups sent by really-infected PCs over the LAN and the intertubes.

Comment: I am sure I have enabled and start messenger service on all the computer.

Comment: @grawity, what is infected, and really-infected and intertubes? How to fix these problem?